# Stashy Python Bit Bucket Time out Issue

Tags: python, bitbucket, stashy

I have the following code trying to use stashy, to pull and push to Bit Bucket, Well right now I have code that specifically will just display projects/repositories that are given to my account. Very simple.

```
import stashy 
bitbucket = stashy.connect("https://bitbucket.domain.come:port/projects/asdasd/asd/asdadasd/", "username","password")
print(bitbucket.projects.list())
```

I keep getting this error without any hang or delay, What could be this issue, I am assuming its client sided as again I am not given any delay, making me assume its specifically my machine or my client specifically.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project/ProjectName/test_no_gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(bitbucket.projects.list())
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\stashy\helpers.py", line 78, in list
    return list(self.all())
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\stashy\helpers.py", line 44, in paginate
    response = self._client.get(url, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\stashy\client.py", line 59, in get
    return requests.get(self.url(resource), auth=(self._username, self._password), verify=self._verify, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 279, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 374, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 174, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 417, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 232, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 547, in _new_conn
    strict=self.strict)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at other libs/api's turns out stashy is depreciated? Please correct me if I am wrong. Gathered from other research/looking at best method/practice to get into bit bucket. Looking at atlassian-python-api instead, will report back.

**Edit:** Ended up using REST API, and Requests. All these libs, happened to be out of date.